# Placeholders in import statement in go

Tags: go, goimports

I am using the go language and I want to understand the alternative to one scenario that I am facing.

we have import statements in the files as

```
import "github.com/Dir1/Dir2/v101/ServiceName"
```

I have a dependency on SDK which follows the directory structure like this. It has version_no directory.

Problem - Every-time the SDK version is updated we have to replace the import statement with appropriate version.

**Currently in project it is achieved using the sed command which is very heavy operation as we have thousands of files.**
Ex Changing "github.com/Dir1/Dir2/v101/ServiceName" ==> "github.com/Dir1/Dir2/v102/ServiceName"

SDK team will not provide any support so we have to find the good way to resolve this.

I need your suggestion about how this can be achieved.

Comment: You could use Go module's `replace` directive.

Answer (score 0):

Add this in the `go.mod` file:

```
replace github.com/Dir1/Dir2/v101/ServiceName => github.com/Dir1/Dir2/v102/ServiceName
```

Now, you can keep using `github.com/Dir1/Dir2/v101/ServiceName` everywhere, and update this `replace` directive every time the version needs to be updated. For example, if the next version is `v103`, update this:

```
replace github.com/Dir1/Dir2/v101/ServiceName => github.com/Dir1/Dir2/v103/ServiceName
```